# Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage for a single User

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Heey

I have a really strange error with a User when he tries to connect to my ASP.Net web page he Allays get this strange error  as you can see on this pic here  [image]

I already tried to delete the cache and tried to use a different Browser but nothing is really working. And this problem appears only on his Machine

On the internet there are so much different solutions for this problem like change something in the host file or do some stuff in the registry. etc.. but somehow I can not believe that any of these is the right solution for my problem ... and the user is connect to our VPN etc...

Thanks for any help and fast answer

Comment: did you check the proxy settings for the internet explorer on that machine ?

Comment: @ManishGupta  I mean they should be oke he can connect everywhere else even on our inside stuff

Comment: in that case there might be different scenarios based upon the OS, Windows Update etc, - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956196

Comment: @ManishGupta this link does not help me ...

Comment: well, i guess above link includes common scenario for this type of error, but if you sure that those are not a problem. Then perhaps it is difficult to diagnose the error with out having the actual environment.